# How to make an database structure with handling multiple service in a Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am making a site that has many services to buy, my problem is to find the best way to make an ERD for this structure!

as I show an image I have a routine system for making a contract for a user, in another word I have a simple table to insert a contract and its related information for user and member.

I store all relation of Contract tables in **Junction** table. but my problem is that I have many services that have a different price that calculates with its own circumstance( **FirstServicePrice**, **SecoundServicePrice **, **ThirthServicePrice** and ...).

I decide to use a junction in name of JunctionForFindPrice for keeping each service primary for a contract. 4 example if someone buys the first service I keep just FirstServicePrice ID in  JunctionForFindPrice table in FirstServicePriceId field and leave another field null, and then store Id of JunctionForFindPrice in Junction Table (Gray table in Figure).

**is it the best Way for this Implementation? is it the correct way?**

[image: figure]

Comment: Google stackoverflow database/sql/table FK with subtyping (also polymorphism/heirarchies) & re table/column type tag/variant. Multiple FK columns is generally an antipattern. Google re FK to many/multiple/2 tables & re multiple/many/2 exclusive FKs. As such this is a faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are as many pricing schemas as there are applications because everyone does it a little differently, so don't worry: we've all been confused by how to do this the "right" way. One common method is to create a table like [Orders] with fields like [ClientID], [DateOrdered], and [OrderedBy], and another table,[OrderLineItems], that contains each [ServiceID] they add to the order and the price for that service stored as a number ($23.99). Instead of a price junction table, you would have a function or stored procedure that determines the client's price for that service as it's added to the OrderLineItems table.

In my primary application we have a table of "standard prices" for each service with start/stop dates: that allows us to set up price increases in the future. Then we have a table of possible discounts that allow three types of discount, set the new price, discount by x%, or discount by x$. "Discounts" can be negative where we want to charge clients more. This makes for a very flexible pricing structure but the code to figure it all out is very complicated and brittle.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that`s good idea! but is it recommended way to separate price list and insert just final calculated price in my orderLineItem? could you please show me an ERD that use this solution ?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend it because the price AT THAT TIME is now immortalized on that invoice. Otherwise, if your price model changes and you need to look back (say to re-create the invoice), you would need to make sure the price you pull is the correct price for that time, along with any adjustments for bulk discounts, coupons, first-time-user credits, etc. I'll see if I have an ERD lying around...

Comment: Thanks a lot ... :)